# Show Toast from a thread started in a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, toast

I have a BroadcastReceiver.
There I create a new Thread.
How can I show a toast in that thread?

Thanks

Comment: It would be hard to assume your coding, So, Can you upload the code please ?

Comment: what is the problem? what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code for perform UI operation from non-UI thread

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your stuff to update the UI

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This code

```
public void start_insert() {
        pDialog.show();
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int what = 0;
                try {
                    // Do Something in Background
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    what = 1;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler22.sendMessage(handler22.obtainMessage(what));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private Handler handler22 = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                pDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SuccessFull",
                        10).show();

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Activity_Name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your stuff to update the UI

            }
        });
```

Use this code to update UI thread or execute any UI related operation.